# Best SQL client for AWS Athena that supports queries sharing

Tags: sql, jdbc, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I'm looking for the best sql client to use with AWS Athena (with JDBC driver).

One of my needs is to share the queries between users, and I would like to know how can I do it in the best way.

The options I see are:

- Using the web Athena query editor, and save the queries in 'Saved Queries' tab. Generally I prefer to work with a DB software, and not this web tool.
- Using a simple DB client tool (I use DBeaver right now), and share the queries using git. (I find it uncomfortable, because the user will need to choose queries based only on their name, and it might get tricky when there are a lot of queries)

Is there a better way to do it? for example an SQL client that imports the Athena saved queries

Also- I would be interested to find a way and generalize my SQL queries - for example, to edit values in them without changing the query itself. I guess it can be done using some scripting mechanism over the SQL or the DB itself. Any idea how to do this with the client too?...

Thanks!

Comment: I'll expand the question since there is no answer- how will you share SQL queries at all? (regardless of AWS) Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking for a software are off-topic here. This should be asked at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)